# Make Jackson interpret single JSON object as array with one element

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way to make Jackson interpret single JSON object as an array with one element and vice versa?

Example, I have 2 slightly different formats of JSON, I need both to map to same Java object:

Format **A** (JSON array with one element):

```
points : [ {
    date : 2013-05-11
    value : 123
}]
```

Format **B** (JSON object, yes I know it looks "wrong" but it's what I'm given):

```
points : {
    date : 2013-05-11
    value : 123
}
```

Target Java object that both of the above should convert to:

```
//Data.java 
public List<Point> points;
//other members omitted

//Point.java
class Point {
    public String date;
    public int value;
}
```

Currently, only **A** will parse properly to Data. I want avoid directly tampering with the JSON itself. Is there some configuration in Jackson I can tamper with in order to make it accept **B** ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try with [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) - it should work for you.

Example:

```
final String json = "{\"date\" : \"2013-05-11\",\"value\" : 123}";

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
final List<Point> points = mapper.readValue(json,
        new TypeReference<List<Point>>() {});
```

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try this out tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't exist in Jackson 1.7.9. What is the relationship between that and the link you sent?

Comment: You should upgrade `Jackson` library to at least version `2.x.x`.

Comment: It is also possible to enable it on a per-field basis, using @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)

Answer (score 9):

The Jackson 1.x-compatible version uses `DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`. So the above answer changes to:

```
final String json = "{\"date\" : \"2013-05-11\",\"value\" : 123}";

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
final List<Point> points = mapper.readValue(json,
    new TypeReference<List<Point>>() {
    });
System.out.println(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can solve the above problem by this code is given below, this works

```
 final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new 
 ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

 objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
 try {
      String jsonInString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(products.get(j));
      InventoryParser inventoryParser = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInString, 
                                       InventoryParser.class);

      System.out.println(inventoryParser.getId());

     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

"InventoryParser" is a POJO Class.
"products.get(j)" is JSON String.