# json to pojo wrong mapping with array

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema2pojo

I am having a problem when I want to be able to map a single Object but also an Array of those object with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`

Please see below example keep in mind that this is a response payload and it is not under my control:

```
{
"GetSomeUserInfoDetails": {
    "ItemListOfUser": {
        "itemList": {
            "item": [
                {
                    "name": "Stack overflow",
                    "adress": "ola"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Google",
                    "adress": "man"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

The [jsontopojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is generating the classes that I can use for this response. The problem occurs when there is only **one** item int itemList user i get the following response:

```
{
"GetSomeUserInfoDetails": {
    "WorkItem": {
        "itemList": {
            "item": {
                "name": "Stack overflow",
                "adress": "ola"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When you generate the classes now you will see a different class structure. Is there a way how we can solve this with Jackson?

Comment: This has already been asked before. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element

Comment: Yes but with that solution all objects are as an array.

Comment: Alright, I get it now :) Can you paste Java code of your model classes?