# Jackson desrialize when JsonProperty is sometimes array and sometimes a single Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson-modules

**I've searched Stack Overflow before posting, but there were no solutions for Jackson.**
Here is a server response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 489881731,
      //rest 
    },
    {
      "update_id": 489881732,
      //rest
    }
  ]
}
```

As you see property `"result"` is an array.
Now this is another response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "id": 211948704,
    "first_name": "ربات ادمین‌های تلگرام",
    "username": "tgAdminsBot"
  }
}
```

Here `"result"` is a single object.
This is my class I want to deserialize content to it. I wrote a **custom deserializer** for `TObject` of course:

```
public class Result
{
    private TObject[] result;
    private boolean ok;

    public void setOk (boolean ok) {//code}

    public void setResult (TObject[] result) {//code}


    public TObject[] getResult () {//code}

    public boolean getOk (){//code}
}
```

So I assumed in my class that "`result"` is an array of `TObject`s. Now what can I do? *Is using `@JsonProperty("result")` for two fields which one is an array of `TObject`s and one is a single `TObject` OK?*
If not what else can I do?

Comment: probably this can help `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element/17004714#17004714 or this : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @varren, please post it as answer so question can be closed properly, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you enable `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` both

`{"result": []}` and

`{"result": {}}` can be parsed as

```
class Result{
   List result;
}
```

[Documentation link](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)

> Feature that determines whether it is acceptable to coerce non-array
>   (in JSON) values to work with Java collection (arrays,
>   java.util.Collection) types. If enabled, collection deserializers will
>   try to handle non-array values as if they had "implicit" surrounding
>   JSON array. This feature is meant to be used for
>   compatibility/interoperability reasons, to work with packages (such as
>   XML-to-JSON converters) that leave out JSON array in cases where there
>   is just a single element in array. Feature is disabled by default.

Demo how to use it for OP input jsons and POJOs:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
Result result = mapper.readValue(Result.class;
```

Can be used with `@JsonFormat` above class or field if you don't like mapper version for some reason

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
```

PS. Other SO questions about this problem: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)