# Gson deserialization - attribute might be array or single object

Tags: java, json, deserialization, json-deserialization, android, gson

Using Gson (Android) to deserialize an external web-api I stumbled upon a problem.

Attribute `A` is a list of objects, as such:

```
{
    A: [
       { /* object */ },
       { /* object */ },
    ]
}
```

However when `A` only contains one object the API returns it as a single object, like this:

```
{
    A: { /* object */ }
}
```

In my target class I have `A` defined like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private AObject[] A;
}
```

This works fine for when attribute is a proper array but fails with following exception for the single-object version:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

Is the any simple way to deserialize the attribute to a array containing only one item? Or do I have to loop through the response and change it before deserialization?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to be prepared to get a list(use pojos)... if the jsonstring is only one element the you have a list with only element....

Comment: Jackson is better suited to do this out of the box. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element).