# Java - Handling either a string or a list as a string

Tags: java, json

I'm having a problem where I'm receiving strings as a typical string or it comes in the form of a list.

For example, I could get:

```
"Hello world"
```

Or I could get:

```
["Hello", "world"]
```

What's the ideal way to detect the second type in a string object and concatenate accordingly?

Sorry, some code for context:

```
String result = "";

try
{
    result = json.getString("result"); //This could be one of the two options above
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: What is the type of it? Do you need to parse the String?

Comment: Expand your question. No one reading this will have any idea what you are on about.

Comment: Can you add some context to the question? Where are you using this? Is it a Java function? A RESTful API? What libraries can you use?

Comment: Sorry, added some context. I am extracting a string from a JSON Object

Comment: So the context is JSON, being parsed in Java. `getString` will only ever get you the first option. You can check if `json.get("result") instanceof JsonArray` to see if it's an array. [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)

Comment: Ok.. now we need a bit more detail :) What is the type of the JSON object? Is it Jackson JSONObject?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject

Comment: It's just standard JSON. Thanks for the comments, sorry for the confusion, thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem please just search before ask questions :)

Comment: Will do! I guess in this case I wasn't sure how to approach asking the question either... Amateur hour.

Comment: If you are using Jackson to deserialize to a Java class that has some collection of Strings you can have Jackson handle a single String as an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element