# Spring Jackson convert json object to java array

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I have a json like below :

> {"key":{"a":"aValue"}}

"key" can contain json object as well as json array. i have created following java object to map this json :

```
Class Output {
  private List<DummyObject> key;
  // setter, getting ommited
}
Class DummyObject {
  private String a;
}
```

So, i want if json is

> {"key":[{"a":"val1"},{"a":"val2"}]}

"key" property of Output class should contain a list of 2 objects, and when the json is

> {"key":{"a":"val1"}}

"key" should contain a list of 1 object only.

I have tried using deserializer but it does not work. Also, i do not want to deserialise `DummyObject` myself.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Jackson interpret single JSON object as array with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the Jackson deserialization feature [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY).

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering        **`{"key":[{"a":"val1"},{"a":"val2"}]}`**

The issue is not in your model with the Output;

```
Class Output {
  private List<DummyObject> key;
  // setter, getting ommited
}
```

Since this represents that `key` as a json array.

But you might want to update the DummyObject:

```
Class DummyObject {
  private String a;
}
```

to

```
Class DummyObject {
  private Map<String,String> a;
}
```

Since {"a":"val1"} is not a valid representation of `DummyObject` or even `String a`.

---

Additionally as pointed out by @tima, for varying length of your JSONArray for "key", you must take a look at how to [Make Jackson interpret single JSON object as array with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003823/make-jackson-interpret-single-json-object-as-array-with-one-element)

---

The final clause of your question:

> Also, I do not want to deserialize DummyObject myself.

You can try and update the Output model(not sure if that would be beneficial from performance perspective) as:

```
Class Output {
  private List<Map<String, String>> key;
  // setter, getting ommited
}
```